# How to get news feed exactly how it appears in facebook homepage newsfeed using api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using `/me/feed` and `/me/home` to get my feed and my homepage feed respectively.
But the /me/home only shows updates from my friends. I am following many people but not friends with them. My facebook homepage shows all the updates including my friends and the people I am following.

How to get the news feed exactly like the one appears in the fb website?

Comment: You can't and that's the point, facebook makes money from ads and ads are all over your newsfeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Fabio said, the Graph API does not support it as of now (and I don't think it'll do that in the future). You can only obtain yours and your friends' feeds using the Graph API.

In order to obtain the feeds from a specific person who's not in your friend list, you need a valid User Access Token from that user with a `read_stream` permission.

There is however a way to read the public feeds of user status updates and page status updates as they are posted to Facebook. This can be done by using the [Public Feed API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/). This will  include all feeds that have their privacy set to ‘public’ are included in the stream. Also, you cannot apply to use the API at this time as its access is limited. Its page says:

> Access to the Public Feed API is restricted to a limited set of media
>   publishers and usage requires prior approval by Facebook. You cannot
>   apply to use the API at this time.

But I think it's just a fancy way of saying that this API is not free and you'll be charged few dollars (which you can find out by getting in touch with someone at Facebook) for using this service.